# User ironpython with modules

Tags: python, c#, .net, ironpython

I am creating a sub counter application using c# and python/ironpython. But when I want to use any module with my python code I get the error no module named .... How can I use ironpython with modules this is what i have done.

part of my c# code

```
using IronPython.Hosting;        
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
engine.ExecuteFile("SomeFile.py")
```

Python code

```
import os
```

Error

```
No module named os
```